# How to redirect vistor to specific url based on his Geographical Region(Country)?

Tags: html, redirect, geolocation, opencart, cpanel

I have two website for my clothing brand www.xxx.com & uk.xxx.com. I want to redirect vistors on www.xxx.com to uk.xxx.com if they are visiting from UK.
Also want to have a general idea about Geographical Redirection and methods to apply it.

I am using cPanel as my sites backend and Opencart for both of my stores. I couldnt find any direct Opencart extension for Geographical Redirection, but if there is, I would love to know about it.

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13857734/redirect-user-to-diffrent-website-based-on-location-ip-address

Comment: A much easier solution could be by checking the browser language - it is not 100% reliable, as somebody located in UK could have Polish language set in the browser, but I guess in such a case this would not be a problem if he sees a `www.site.com` instead of `uk.site.com` URL... In this case just check for `$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']` while the browser default language is the first one (the value could be like `de,en-us;q=0.7,en;q=0.3`)...