# How can I redirect user based on the visitor's country?

Tags: apache, cookies, setcookie

How can I redirect traffic based on the visitor's country? The title is quite self-explanatory.

What I want to do is redirect traffic from certain countries to specific website for example US.******.com and for rest www.****.com,Like Godaddy website does.

I have been successful in redirecting the client to specific websites using Geoip Apache module but the real issue is that even are not able to access the .com website as it redirects us back to the US.****.com

i want to give an option for the client to change his location. More specifically, what I want to do is redirect all the traffic to a web page "X", EXCEPT traffic coming from countries ("A" | "B" | "C"), that will be redirected to another web page "Y".

Is there any other way to successfully do this?

Does anyone know where I can get step-by-step instructions on how to do this? I don't really much about coding/scripting

Any help would be appreciated. Finding a solution to this is really important for me right now!

Thanks,
Sumanth Shetty

Comment: You can check the link below for your query.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13857734/redirect-user-to-diffrent-website-based-on-location-ip-address

Comment: every country has a IP series used. u can set a .htaccess or a code routine to redirect accordingly. even some online plugins are available.