# Redirect main website to sub domain based on visitor IP address (country)

Tags: javascript, redirect, geolocation, freegeoip

I need help redirecting my website to sub domain based on visitor ip address (location). I have 3 specific websites

- I want to redirect visitors from Europe to `eu.mysite.com`
- I want to redirect visitors from USA to `us.mysite.com`
- I want to redirect visitors from rest of the world to `mysite.com`

I tried several codes and modifying htaccess as well, it didn't help as GeoIp not installed on the server.

Comment: There is surely an HTTP API you can use that does a lookup from IP to country? Have you looked at MaxMind? What programming language are you using?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @halfer Javascript

Comment: Ah, just frontend? OK, do a search for "JavaScript country to IP" please, both here on Stack Overflow and on your favourite search engine.

Answer (score 2):

You just use an API to resolve the visitor continent by IP and redirect to the corresponding URL :

```
$.getJSON("http://api.db-ip.com/v2/free/self").then(function(addrInfo) {
    if (addrInfo.continentCode == "EU") {
        document.location = "http://eu.example.com";
    } else if (...) {
        // handle other cases
    } else {
        document.location = "http://example.com";
    }
});
```